# How can I reference parameters of an Object within a passed block?

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming

I'm trying to reference one of the parameters of an Object inside of the block that's passed along with it.

```
def command(attributes = {}, &block)
    yield
end

command(attr_1: 'Open Mike Night', 
    attr_2: 2033392,
    attr_3: [9.29, 10.08, 12.32]) do |event|

    event.message.delete

    puts "#{self.attributes[:attr_1]}" # <-- That didn't work.

end
```

Is something like that possible and if so how would I go about doing it? What should I look into?

Comment: Should the last key be `attr_3`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 You're right, sorry!

Comment: Have you got a `yield` in your `command` definition?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yes. Again sorry I didn't add that in.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head you could do something like this. Caveat being I have no idea if this is suitable for production code.

This code creates instance variables for each key by iterating over the keys of the argument hash. Then when we call `command`, we can reference each key's value in the block using the corresponding instance_variable:

```
def command(attributes = {}, &block)
  attributes.each_key { |key| 
    instance_variable_set("@#{key}",attributes[key])
  }
  yield
end

command(attr_1: 'Open Mike Night',
        attr_2: 2033392,
        attr_3: [9.29, 10.08, 12.32]) do |event|

  puts "#{@attr_1}"
end
```

prints:

```
Open Mike Night
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the method is defined in a different scope than where it's called. The block is scoped by its surroundings, so if `command` is defined in `class A` but the method is called in `class B`, `@attr_1` will be evaluated in the context of `B`, not `A`

Answer (score 0):

Yield them to the block : )

```
def command(attributes = {})
  yield self, attributes
end

attributes = { attr_1: 'Open Mike Night', attr_2: 2033392, attr_3: [9.29, 10.08, 12.32] }

command(attributes) do |obj, attrs|
  p "#{obj.object_id}, #{attrs[:attr_1]}"
end 
# => "70309890142840, Open Mike Night"
```

Any method, constant, or variable available within a method scope can be given as an argument to `yield` to be sent into a block as a block variable. Then you can do with it whatever you wish. In this case `attrs` would be a completely optional variable as well, and the block would be valid without it.

```
command(attributes) { |obj| p obj.object_id } # => 70309890142840
```

P.S. You don't need `&block` in the method signature if you're using `yield`. You also weren't giving `yield` an argument in your question, but were passing an `|event|` variable into the block, which would have been `nil`. So I just left that out in the above example.